# native libraries are not loaded in java application

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have to find system information in an applications and for this I have two native library files as given below:
`SystemManagerLinux.so` and `SystemManagerWin32.dll`.

I have to use these library files in my java code to show the information on java GUI. I have put these files on the location: `C:\Users\surjit\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SampleMonitor` and give it is as vm argument in my netbeans ide on run option as given below:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\surjit\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SampleMonitor"
```

and call the libraries as in the code :

```
if (os.startsWith("Linux"))
   loadTmpLibrary("SystemManagerLinux.so", "libSML", ".so");
else if (os.startsWith("Windows")) {
   loadTmpLibrary("SystemManagerWin32.dll", "SMW", ".dll");
```

But when I am running the application it is giving following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:     SystemManagerWin32.fetchProcessIDs([I)I
    at SystemManagerWin32.fetchProcessIDs(Native Method)
    at SystemMonitor.refreshPidList(SystemMonitor.java:168)
    at SystemMonitor.<init>(SystemMonitor.java:383)
    at SystemMonitor.main(SystemMonitor.java:494)
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:    SystemManagerWin32.fetchSystemMemoryStatus(LSystemMemoryStatus;)Z
    at SystemManagerWin32.fetchSystemMemoryStatus(Native Method)
    at SystemMonitor.run(SystemMonitor.java:410)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Please suggest me solution.Thanks

Comment: What does 'os' actually start with?

Comment: os is a string variable which get a property os.name as given below:  String os = System.getProperty("os.name");

Comment: Use JNA and skip the native libraries altogether.

Comment: You haven't answered the question. What did it *actually start with when you executed this code?* In other words, did either of the load calls actually execute?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the native methods you're attempting to call don't exist in your DLL, not that your DLL fails to be loaded.

Assuming `loadTmpLibrary` effectively performs a `System.loadLibrary()` call, you need to ensure that your native methods are declared properly.  Usually invoking `javah` on the Java source which includes the native declarations is sufficient to get an accurate header.  Compare its output with whatever it is you're currently compiling.